# connect bluetooth classic keyboard to arduino or similar (ESP32..)

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, keyboard, esp32

I tried connecting a Bluetooth remote control (Bluetooth behaves like a Bluetooth keyboard) to an Arduino Nano 33 BLE and also to various ESP32. No success so far.

It seems to me that there is no way to do this now – right?
Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Dirk

My results:

1. Arduino Nano 33 BLE not working because BLE is not compatible with “classic” Bluetooth (right?)
2. ESP32 with classic Bluetooth does not work due to missing Bluetooth HID host class.
3. The HC-05 wireless Bluetooth module does not work due to lack of Bluetooth HID host function.
4. There is a workaround where I could use a Raspberry Pi or a smartphone as a relay. But I would connect a Bluetooth keyboard directly to an Arduino or similar.
5. Web research shows no solution. The other way to make an Arduino Bluetooth keyboard is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how did you search but:

1. Yes, Arduino Nano 33 is BLE only device.
2. ESP32 has HID host API: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_hidh.html
3. HC-05 can be flashed with HID support: https://www.instructables.com/Upgrade-Your-3-Bluetooth-Module-to-Have-HID-Firmwa/
4. Depends on your needs.
5. 5 seconds of googling (2,3) and first links gave what you need.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was blind. I will try point 2.